# CSng function raises exception called with object that is Nothing

Tags: vb.net

When I call CSng(MyObj) where MyObj is Nothing it raises exception "Nullable Object must have a value"

So to test further, I called  CSng(Nothing) - (using a hardcoded Nothing value), it returns 0.

Can anyone explain this to me?

```
    Dim it As Single?
    it = Nothing
    Dim it2 As Single = CSng(it)   ' Exception here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange thing to do in the first place. `it` is already a `Nullable(Of Single)`. Calling `CSng()` involves a lot of extra baggage that having a `Nullable(Of Single)` will allow you to avoid. This should work much better:

```
Dim it As Single? = Nothing
Dim it2 As Single = it.GetValueOrDefault()
```

Comment: nice, I didn't know about the GetValueOrDefault method. It realizes my objective, a concise way to coerce the nullable int to an int.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `it` as a nullable Single, so there is no problem assigning `Nothing` to it. But `CSng(it)` is trying to convert that value to a regular (not nullable) Single which can't store the value `Nothing` and that is why you are getting the exception.

You need to decide what you want to do if `it` is `Nothing`. For example, if you want `it2` to be 0.0 if `it` is `Nothing` you can use the following code:

```
Dim it As Single? = Nothing
Dim it2 As Single = If(it Is Nothing, 0, CSng(it))
```

Comment: ok, but still don't know why `Dim it2 As Single = CSng(Nothing)` returns 0 without an exception.

Comment: @BrusterMulligan Yes, that surprises me as well. I would have expected it to throw an exception just as the code in your original question does.